# How to check if a space in a 3d array is open/empty

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, enums

I am struggling with my code right now, I am making it in Unity but because it isn't Unity related but more coding in general, I thought it was a better idea to put it here.

#### Background info

Anyways, let me explain a bit of background information. I have an array of enums called BlockType, the BlockType enum contains Air or Stone. And my array is a 3d array, I called it blocks and is declared like this `blocks = new BlockType[50,50,50]` (note: all blocks are then initialized to air)

I also have Features, for now Features are just basic rooms, they are given a size, and are just placing blocks with their position as the origin. And lastly, PosDirObj are just objects that contain a position (Vect3) and a direction (Vect2, which is either `(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0),(0,-1)`). I use those to store the position and direction of the features since I won't need them once they are placed, so there is no point in putting it inside feature.

#### Question

Anyways, my problem is, I am trying to find out whether or not the room will fit in my array, meaning that at every position where the room will be, there are only Air Blocks, I am also adding a 1 block padding of checking around the actual room dimensions just to keep space for later. And right now it either tells me it's right when sometimes it's not, and most of the time, it tells me it's wrong when it's is right, I think the direction system is messed up, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
  public bool FeatureFitsInWorld (Feature feature, MathDR.PosDirObj wall)
  {
        // Get required parameters
        Vect3 pos = new Vect3(wall.position.x + Mathf.Abs(wall.direction.x),
                              wall.position.y,
                              wall.position.z + Mathf.Abs(wall.direction.y)); // Gets the position where the starting point will be (adding wall.direction.x/y because there's a padding)
        Vect3 size = feature.size; // The size the room will be
        Vector2 dir = ConvertDirToFitDir(wall.direction); // The direction, btw, this function just changes all 0s to 0.5f, Vector2s are using floats, Vect2s are using ints
        //Vect2 dir = wall.direction; //Using this for testing... Useless for now

        // Checks if the feature doesn't go out of bounds
        if (pos.x + (size.x * (int)dir.x) > worldSize.x ||
            pos.x + (size.x * (int)dir.x) < 0 ||
            pos.y + size.y > worldSize.y ||
            pos.y < 0 ||
            pos.z + (size.z * (int)dir.y) > worldSize.z ||
            pos.z + (size.z * (int)dir.y) < 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Feature goes out of bounds! at pos " + pos + " with size " + size + " and direction " + dir);
            return false;
        }

        // Checks if all blocks are Air
        for (int x = -1; x < size.x + 1; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < size.y; y++)
            {
                for (int z = -1; z < size.z + 1; z++)
                {
                    // Checks if the block we are looking at is air,
                    // add some coordinates because else it would just search for an absolute position if the room was placed at 0,0,0, which we are not
                    if (blocks[pos.x + (int)(x * dir.x),
                               pos.y + y,
                               pos.z + (int)(z * dir.y)] != BlockType.Air)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Found that block isn't air at " + (pos.x + (int)(x * dir.x)) + " " + (pos.y + y) + " " + (pos.z + (int)(z * dir.y)) + " ");
                        return false;
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code? What seems to be the problem? I have been re-writing this function twice now and I still don't know why it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are doing here, but it looks like you are multiplying your z's with your y's: `pos.z + (size.z * (int)dir.y) > worldSize.z` You are doing something similar when you check if your blocks are not equal to air.

Comment: Yes, that's because direction is only x,y but because all my rooms are to be at the same level, I just use that instead of using (0,0,1), instead I just do (0,1)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, was able to solve the problem thanks to Chris in PM.

Here's the code for anyone that might need it, anyways thanks a lot!

```
public bool FeatureFits(Feature feature, MathDR.PosDirObj wall)
    {
        // Get required parameters
        Vect3 dir = wall.direction;
        Vect3 pos = wall.position;
        Vect3 size = feature.size;

        if (dir.x == 0)
            dir.x = 1;
        if (dir.y == 0)
            dir.y = 1;
        if (dir.z == 0)
            dir.z = 1;

        int padding = 1;

        int x1 = pos.x - padding;
        int x2 = pos.x + (size.x * dir.x) + padding;

        int y1 = pos.y - padding;
        int y2 = pos.y + (size.y * dir.y) + padding;

        int z1 = pos.z - padding;
        int z2 = pos.z + (size.z * dir.z) + padding;

        // Check if outside bounds
        if (x1 < 0 ||
            x2 < 0 ||
            y1 < 0 ||
            y2 < 0 ||
            z1 < 0 ||
            z2 < 0 ||
            x1 > worldSize.x ||
            x2 > worldSize.x ||
            y1 > worldSize.y ||
            y2 > worldSize.y ||
            z1 > worldSize.z ||
            z2 > worldSize.z) {
            return false;
        }

        // Checks for every block that the feature will take + 1 padding
        for (int x = System.Math.Min(x1, x2); x <= System.Math.Max(x1, x2); x++)
        {
            for (int y = System.Math.Min(y1, y2); y <= System.Math.Max(y1, y2); y++)
            {
                for (int z = System.Math.Min(z1, z2); z <= System.Math.Max(z1, z2); z++)
                {
                    if (blocks[x, y, z] != BlockType.Air)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Btw, I changed a bit of the code like dir to a Vect3 just to make it a bit more flexible.